# NodeJS firebase-admin cannot send email verification link

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm using node firebase-admin to manage user as follow.

```
function (req, res, next) {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const auth = getAuth();
  const userRecord = await auth.createUser({ email, password });
  auth.generateEmailVerificationLink(email).then(console.log);
  // this log verify link successfully xyz.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=...
  await accountService.createAccount({ id: userRecord.uid, email })
  res.status(200).json(userRecord);
}
```

I also tried different email and also debug `auth.generateEmailVerificationLink` function and saw it invoked to firebase auth api and succeed. But cannot find email in mail box or spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`generateEmailVerificationLink` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth.md#baseauthgenerateemailverificationlink) of the Firebase Admin SDK only [generates the link you would put into a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_verification_link). Once the link is generated, you then need to embed that link into a message and then send the email using whatever service you desire.

If you want to use the built-in email verification methods, you must use the appropriate `sendVerificationEmail` method of the [client-side SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries#client-sdks).

> The Firebase Client SDKs provide the ability to send users emails containing links they can use for password resets, email address verification, and email-based sign-in. These template-based emails are sent by Google and have limited customizability.

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman. This answers why I can not receive email. But it create an other problem. The `sendVerificationEmail` requires `currentUser` but in my case I don't use client SDK `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` so I can't use `sendVerificationEmail` directly after request success.

Comment: Is there any way to reuse response from firebase-admin to log in as current user?
```
  const userRecord = await auth.createUser({ email, password });
```

Comment: @SyTranDung The admin SDKs don't have an equivalent of `sendVerificationEmail` because the API it uses relies on anti-spam methods based on things like an IP address. You are expected to send email from your code using tools like Mailgun, NodeMailer, SendGrid, etc.